# How do I read and change lines in a command script with VB?

Tags: rdp

Short Version: I know there is not an easy way to do this but how do I change line in a command file with VB?

Long: Working in a login script that will(eventually) populate an RDP file for a specific user based on their username(IE: user@blahdeblah.com goes to 
full address:s:blahdeblah.blahdeblah.com and so forth). Multiple server location in part one of the address. I've done the easy part of pulling the file up, capturing the username and where they should be going, but I lack the knowledge on how to populate the file. I've seen some posts here about reading the text and then changing the words as they would appear in a column, but would the same practice work in rows?

If the overall text file in the RDP is 47 rows could I just say "replace row 45 with *_*"?

I know that was a pain to read through.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd almost certainly want to do something more like find the line with "full address" and then replace it with the other line, line numbers are a pretty breakable thing. I'm not where I can easily test the whole thing, but you want something like:

```
Dim oFSO
Dim inTS,OutTS
Dim tline
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inTS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("default.rdp",1,1)
Set outTS = oFSO.CreateTextFile("mynew.rdp", true,true)
While inTS.AtEndOfStream = false 
tline = inTS.ReadLine
If InStr(1,tline,"full address:",1) > 0 Then 
WScript.Echo("found " &InStr(tline,"full address:"))
outTs.WriteLine("full address:s:SERVER")
Else
outTs.WriteLine(tline)
End If
Wend       
inTS.Close
outTS.Close
```

Though you might have some trouble with unicode you might have better luck with something like running gnuwin32's sed version